# Chrome - Keyboard shortcut to activate reader mode?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using Google Chrome 92.0.4515.159 (current latest stable version) on macOS and have enabled reader mode in `chrome://flags`.

I can activate reader mode by clicking on the reader mode icon at the right end of the URL bar, but it's not associated with a keyboard shortcut.

Is there anyway to bind a keyboard shortcut to activate reader mode? Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't have a menu item for it, so you can't key-command it the regular way. Safari does, it's Cmd/Shift/R.

Answer (score 5):

I stumbled on your post as the top hit when I was trying to find a solution; I don't know if you're still looking but for any other wanderers ... if you're using the [reader extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/reader-view/ecabifbgmdmgdllomnfinbmaellmclnh?hl=en) then I noticed that the release notes say:

> 0.1.5: It is now possible to toggle the reader view using keyboard shortcut (define one from Chrome's settings page)

I had to figure out how to do the defining and found a helpful write up [here](https://www.alphr.com/customize-chrome-hotkeys/). Basically: go to `chrome://extensions/shortcuts` scroll down to the plug-in's section and add your preferred keystrokes. Useful to know for other things I suspect.

**Next Mission:** find a single keystroke to <enter reader mode and print/ save to PDF>. If anyone's got a solution to that then I'd love to hear it. I've messed about with the [shortkeys extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck?hl=en) but don't know any javascript & haven't been able to make it do anything really clever.

---

BTW: @Tetsujin - I thoroughly agree, I'm doing the de-google-your-life thing and moving to self-hosting as much as possible but ... workplace websites demand use of chrome to work properly, I use chromium and brave when I can but paying the bills is a pretty significant motivator.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I didn't use a Chrome extension, I used Alfred on macOS to run a python script when I press a hotkey that clicks a predefined coordinate on the screen, which is where the reader view button is located.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR;
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> then <kbd>Tab</kbd>... and finally <kbd>Enter</kbd>

This solution isn't actually a hotkey but rather a workaround compirsing of a keystroke sequence that gets your keyboard focus at the reader mode toggle icon where you would need to push <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> as the final step to activate reader mode for the current page.

Presss <kbd>Ald</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> - this will set keyboard focus to the address bar and select all the URL string in it.

Then you need to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> button one to three times depending on the number of icons the address bar contains for the current page at its right. Sometimes Reader Mode icon is right next to the address bar, sometimes there are two more icons before it (like, for example, zoom and G-icon toggling google search side panel as in front of me right now).

Note, that, for this to work, Reader mode must be enabled in Chrome Flags settings as well as in Chrome Settings.
To enable Reader Mode, type `chrome://flags` in the adress bar and then type `reader mode` in the search bar at the top of the page or just copy-paste this string `chrome://flags/#enable-reader-mode` to the addres bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You'll see four options, namely:

- Default
- Enabled
- Enabled available in settings
- Disabled

Choose `Enabled` or `Enabled available in settings`, latter means that you would additionally have to enable `Reader Mode` in Chrome settings at the bottom of the `Appearance` page.

The advantage of this solution is that it doesn't require installing any additional extensions and works with any Chrome installation just out of the box.